# Finding out which cluster a new data entered belongs to and returning the other items in the same cluster

Tags: python, cluster-analysis, prediction

I have a set of product data with specifications etc. 
I have applied kmode clustering to the dataset to form clusters of the most similar products.

When I enter a new data, I want to know which cluster this data belongs to and what are the other products( which are almost same as this new product). How do I go about this?

Answer (score 0):

Use the nearest neighbors.

No need to rely on clustering, which tends to be unstable and produce *unbalanced* clusters. It's fairly common to have 90% of your data rightfully in the same cluster (e.g. a "normal users" cluster, or a "single visit" cluster). So you should ask yourself: what do you *gain* by doing this, what is the cost-benefit ratio?